# Insert 1 hundred millions of records on RocksDB

Tags: c++, bulkinsert, rocksdb

I'm trying to insert 1 hundred millions of records on RocksDB but i get SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault, after 287481 insert on this line:

```
0   ??  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6     0x7ffff6086341  
1   rocksdb::Slice::Slice   slice.h 43  0x40efd5    
2   main    main.cpp    75  0x40e857
```

here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   rocksdb::DB *db;
   rocksdb::Options options;
   options.create_if_missing=true;
   rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options,"/tmp/testdb1",&db);
   assert(status.ok());
   for (long var = 0; var < 100000000L; ++var) {
       db->Put(rocksdb::WriteOptions(),""+var,"v"+var);
       qDebug()<<var;
   }
}
```

Thank you for ur help.

Comment: hwo does Slice::Slice look like? Also you say one hundred million, but in reality you only insert 1 million entries

Comment: it's one hundred million i've correct it.

Comment: maybe you try to insert stuff that is bigger then your heap, so you get SIGSEGV. Just a guess, because I cant say anymore without seeing more code

Comment: so how to increase heap size? thanks

Comment: you cant really(You can install more ram). It is basically the memory available on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be adding "k" (const char*) and var (long). Please construct the string like this:

std::string key("k" + std::to_string(var));

And same thing for the value.